# Odoo change inventory_value in stock.quant

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I need to change inventory value in stock.quant, I want to add shipping cost and technician cost (A technician is specified in each sale order line, he has a cost for checking the product). I have overridden the '_get_inventory_value' function in stock.py

```
def _get_inventory_value(self, cr, uid, quant, context=None):
        print quant.reservation_id.procurement_id.sale_line_id.technician_sale.price
        return (quant.product_id.standard_price + quant.reservation_id.procurement_id.sale_line_id.technician_sale.price)* quant.qty
```

This code works only for confirmed sale orders, that is because for confirmed orders there will be a resevation_id from there I can get the sale order line and technician cost (quant.reservation_id.procurement_id.sale_line_id.technician_sale.price). But for a delivered order there are no reservation_ids hence I cannot get the sale_order_line. Is there any method to get sale_order_line from stock.quant of a delivered order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delivered order (model `stock.picking`) have a field **Source Document** (`origin`), so using **origin** you can get the record of `sale.order` and  `sale.order.line` 
[image]